# Why preg_replace is removing + sign from string? I want + sign to include

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

String: `Two + Two & One + One ?`

How to include `+` sign. I don't want to remove `+` sign at same time replacing `&` with `-`. I used following

```
$string = preg_replace('/&#?[\+\sA-Za-z0-9]+;/i', '-', $string);
```

It gives result: `Two  Two - One  One ?`

Required Result: `Two + Two - One + One ?`

**Note:** You can suggest any preg_replace which let include + sign & replace & with -. I am on WordPress website.

I didn't find any answer for my problem on stackoverflow. Everyone is talking about removing `+` sign. But I want it to include.

Comment: The fact that you are getting `&amp;` to work means that your string is not actually what you shared but html encoded.

Comment: `[\+\sA-Za-z0-9]+` matches 1 or more chars in the character set, and `+` is there. Remove it if you do not want to remove it.

Comment: @apokryfos I don't understand what you are saying about `&amp;` . I just need to include + sign & replace & with -. Whatever the method is available.

Comment: `&amp;` is not in the string you shared is what I'm saying. Are you sure that is the actual string you're working with?

Comment: You updated your regex to `&#?`. Do you also want to replace `&#` with a dash? Perhaps you can add some more examples that you want to replace to your question.

Comment: I think whatever everyone is suggesting is correct. Because even my `preg_replace('/&#?[\+\sA-Za-z0-9]+;/i', '-', $string);` let + sign include but something else is stripping out it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex, this is what you need:

```
<?php

$regex = '#\&(amp;)?#';
echo preg_replace($regex, '-', 'Two + Two & One + One ?') . "\n";
echo preg_replace($regex, '-', 'Two + Two &amp; One + One ?') . "\n";
```

Output:

```
Two + Two - One + One ? 
Two + Two - One + One ?
```

Which you can see here https://3v4l.org/s1tVW

And play with the regex here https://regex101.com/r/G7CbKF/1

Comment: It removed string after "Two   Two -".

Comment: not with my code, click the 3v4l link and see for yourself

Comment: Yes, it works there. but don't know why it is not working in my wordpress website.

Comment: just use MY regex, get rid of that stuff

Answer (score 0):

use this one

$string = preg_replace('/&/i', '-', $string);

Comment: he needs &amp; not &, it's an html entity